# How to Print decimal Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select total_hours, total_hour_present,
 (total_hour_present / total_hours) * 100 as total_hour_present 
from attendancereport_subject 
where roll_no = '08ME001'
```

Comment: Is this a question ?

Comment: what is the data type of `total_hours` and `total_hour_present`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select total_hours,
   total_hour_present,
   (cast (total_hour_present as decimal) / total_hours) * 100 as total_hour_present 
from attendancereport_subject 
where roll_no = '08ME001'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing decimals in the result, then that leads to the assumption that both "total_hour_present" and "total_hours" are integers.

Because in  SQL Server, when an INT is divided by an INT then it returns an INT.

So you could cast or convert the total_hours to a float or a decimal.
So that the division returns a number with decimal values.

**Example 1**

```
(total_hour_present / cast(total_hours as decimal(10,0))) * 100 as percentage_hour_present
```

**Example 2**

```
(total_hour_present / convert(float, total_hours)) * 100 as percentage_hour_present
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but if the 2 hour columns are integers then you will most probably get zero, since the result will always be less than 1. So try something like this:

```
convert(decimal(10,2),(convert(decimal(10,2),total_hour_present) / total_hours) * 100) as total_hour_present
```

Answer (score 0):

below should work

```
select total_hours, total_hour_present,
 ((total_hour_present*1.00) / (total_hours*1.00)) * 100.000 as total_hour_present 
from attendancereport_subject 
where roll_no = '08ME001'
```

Comment: select total_hours, total_hour_present,
 cast((total_hour_present*1.00) as decimal / (total_hours*1.00)) * 100.000 as total_hour_present 
from attendancereport_subject 
where roll_no = '08ME001'

Comment: @PrakashKumar any problem?

Comment: Can't display decimal Values then  use Cast or convert function  to Display the output

Answer (score -1):

you need to cast the value to decimal, Try this:

```
 select total_hours, total_hour_present,
    (cast(total_hour_present as decimal(18,0)) / total_hours) * 100 as 
    total_hour_present 
    from attendancereport_subject 
    where roll_no = '08ME001'
```